# Trigger li wrapper on click of ng-disabled button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `button` which is wrapped with `li` tag.

```
<li class="right" 
    ng-click="isError(locationForm.$invalid)" 
    ng-if="action == 'add'">

    <button ng-disabled="locationForm.$invalid" 
            ng-click="addLocation(location)" 
            class="options active">Save        
    </button>

</li>
```

Since I cannot get the onclick event of `disabled` button, I wrapped it with `li` and on click I'm planning to notify the user about the error.

```
$scope.isError = function(error){
     console.log(error);
     if(error){
          ngNotify.set('Your notification message goes here!');
     }
}
```

But `ng-click` on `li` tag is not getting triggered when the button is `disabled` for some reason. Not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the button on a `span` and putting the `ng-click` to the span instead?

Comment: try removing the ng-if statement

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro Tried wrapper `span` but no luck.

Comment: @RaviShankar Tried with removing `ng-if` still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a solution is to replace `ng-disabled="locationForm.$invalid"` with `ng-class={'disabled': locationForm.$invalid}` and then HTML:

```
<button ng-class="{'disabled': locationForm.$invalid}"
        ng-click="addLocation(location, locationForm.$invalid)" 
        class="options active">Save        
</button>
```

And in JS:

```
$scope.addLocation = function (location, error) {
    if(error){
          ngNotify.set('Your notification message goes here!');
          return;
     }
     //rest stuff when no error
}
```

By the way, you should really avoid using `$scope` in favour to components or at least `controller as` syntax, unless you really have to (stick to Angular 1.2 or legacy code).

Comment: Thanks @Pneumokok, that really helped.